# How do I open vscode:extension links from Chrome or Edge in OSS Dev?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to investigate [issue #40848](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40848). In order to see what is going on I wanted to have vscode:extension links from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com open in OSS Dev version of vscode, rather than in the normal Visual Studio Code, while debugging.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The url scheme is just `code-oss:extensions`.

Code-OSS cannot connect to the extension marketplace by default however, so the install itself will not work. Not sure if this blocks you from debugging. If you need to connect OSS to the marketplace, please try reaching out to someone on the vscode repo. We don't publish official information on how to do that